# Firefox doesn't call the `beforeunload` event unless I click the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I want to handle the `beforeunload` event in Firefox. It is working fine except that the user needs to manually click the page or write something into an input.

I have the following piece of code that works on Firefox, but again, only if we *manually* click the page.

```
<script>
    popMessage = "Foo";
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        (e || window.event).returnValue = popMessage;     //Gecko + IE
        alert(popMessage);
        return popMessage;
   });
</script>
```

I tried to add:

- `document.body.click()`
- `<input type='text' autofocus>`

Both are not making any change.

I also tried to use jQuery with the hope that it will handle it correctly. Still, getting the same:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
   });
</script>
```

These work fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Is there any hope to get this working without user interaction on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[developer.mozilla.org](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) states that "To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with." So there is no hope.